# Errors highlighting differences between sheets and copy to new sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

In essence, I want to compare two sheets, one containing data from Today, the other from Yesterday, and then copy the lines with changes to a third sheet.

The code I am currently using (seen below) mostly works but has a couple errors (also broken out below) that I want to iron out.

```
Sub Changed()
set wsa = Sheets("Today")
Set wsb = Sheets("Yesterday")
Set wse = Sheets("Line Changes")

Dim mycell as range
Dim mydiff as integer

For each mycell in wsa.usedrange
     If Not mycell.Value = wsb.Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
          mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(250, 250, 50)
          mycell.Range("B").Interior.Color = RGB (250, 250, 50)
          mycell.EntireRow.Copy wse.Range("A" & Rows.Count).xlUp).Offset(1)
     End If
Next

End Sub
```

Breakdown of the individual desired functions and issues within the loop:

`If Not mycell.Value = wsb.Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then`

Compare Sheets("Today") and Sheets("Yesterday") to find differences. This line works.

`mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(250, 250, 50)`

Highlight the changed items on Sheets("Today"). This line works.

`mycell.Range("B").Interior.Color = RGB (250, 250, 50)`

For reference, Column A is just a general reference number which has no real bearing on the rest of the data, but Column B contains an alpha-numeric code specific to the actual items in each line which is why I want to highlight column B instead of A if there are changes.

Highlight Column B in Sheets("Today") if there are changes in the line to allow for easy identification of lines containing changes. The issue I run into with this function is that it doesn't actually work. It doesn't give me an error message so I haven't been able to actually identify what the problem is. This particular function is not 100% necessary so I would be amenable to just removing it.

`mycell.EntireRow.Copy wse.Range("A" & Rows.Count).xlUp).Offset(1)`

Copy rows with changes from Sheets("Today") and paste it in Sheets("Line Changes"). The issue I run into with this function is it copies changed lines multiple times, once for every individual change.

For example, if Columns D,E,F, and G all have changes, "D" will be highlighted and the row will be copied, then "E" will be highlighted and the row will be copied, and so on. Obviously that's not ideal if there's dozens of lines with 5 or 6 changes each.

My main issue is with that last line, I think the easiest fix would be to remove it from the current loop and add it back in later in the code so it doesn't copy over every individual change but past attempts of mine to remove it broke everything. Its a pretty large document, (1500ish rows, 32 columns) so looping the same data potentially a couple hundred times tends to crash excel. Any suggestions to fix this issue or even streamline the process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post a data example? Also, what columns do you want to compare? Because right now you are comparing every single cell in `usedrange` and that maybe be time consumming (besides the problem you describe as *Obviously that's not ideal if there's dozens of lines with 5 or 6 changes each.*

Comment: I don't think `range("B")` is valid? I could not get `range("B").Interior.Color = ...` to work. `range("B1").entirecolumn.Interior.Color = ...` did work. Try that?

Comment: @garbb or maybe Range("B:B").Interior.Color ?

Comment: also for line `mycell.EntireRow.Copy wse.Range("A" & Rows.Count).xlUp).Offset(1)` parentheses are not balanced. This line must be a typo or something? [xlup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection) is a constant and supposed to be a parameter of some method like [Range.End](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end).

Comment: @garbb Good catch, it's supposed to be ```.end(xlup)``` I had to hand type this over from a different system so I must've missed that. I also tried to run ```Range("B1").EntireColumn``` (highlighted the sheet) and @DS_London 's ```Range("B:B")``` and also ```Range("B1:B")``` with no dice. That line's not really even needed so I think at this point I'll shelve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HighLighting Differences: a Row Range Approach

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Changed()
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define worksheets.
    Dim wsa As Worksheet
    Set wsa = wb.Worksheets("Today")
    Dim wsb As Worksheet
    Set wsb = wb.Worksheets("Yesterday")
    Dim wse As Worksheet
    Set wse = wb.Worksheets("Line Changes")
    
    ' Define Today Used Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wsa.UsedRange
    
    Dim RowRange As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim copyRow As Boolean
    
    ' Loop through rows of Today Used Range.
    For Each RowRange In rng.Rows
        ' Initialize Copy Row Boolean.
        copyRow = False
        ' Loop through each cell in current row of Today Used Range.
        For Each cel In RowRange.Cells
            ' Ceck value in current cell on Today worksheet against the value
            ' of the same cell on Yesterday Worksheet.
            If Not cel.Value = wsb.Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column).Value Then
                ' Set Copy Row Boolean to True indicating that this
                ' row will be copied and the value in "B" column will be
                ' hightlighted.
                copyRow = True
                ' Highlight current cell in Today Worksheet.
                cel.Interior.Color = RGB(250, 250, 50)
            End If
        Next cel
        ' If any differences have been found...
        If copyRow Then
            RowRange.Cells(2).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 250, 50)
            RowRange.Copy wse.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks for the help and for explaining what every line actually does.